# Android MVP - View unit tests - setting the presenter

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-mvp

I want to write unit tests for my `MainActivity`. The activity has a `MainPresenter`. The presenter has a method `A()` that needs to be called inside `onCreate()` of the `Activity`

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity implements MainContract.View {
    private MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      presenter = new MainPresenter(this);
      ...
      presenter.A();

    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a unit test that mocks the `MainPresenter`, and then checks if the method `A()` was called. Currently, I think that testing whether the method of a mock of the Presenter was called is impossible. My question is - what do I need to change to make it testable?

Answer (score 0):

Use Robolectric:

```
    activity = Robolectric
            .buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
            .create().get()
```

and in your MainActivity provide presenter using Dependency Injection.

EDIT:

If you don't want to change much code than you can also stub constructor of your MainPresenter:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(MainPresenter.class).withArguments(YOUR_ARGUMENTS).thenReturn(MOCKED_PRESENTER);
```

Comment: I am using Robolectric. The problem is the second part of your answer, because inside one method we create and use the same object

Comment: I understand - as I wrote I suggest using DI. That's how  UT should be done. But if you would like to avoid big code refactor than mock constructors. I've edited my answer